# Kalman Filter Library

Tags: c++, kalman-filter

I just downloaded the kFilter library (http://kalman.sourceforge.net/), and had some questions about its use that I couldn't find in the documentation.  Has anyone used this library in the past?

My questions are basically these:

1. The Step function of the eKFilter receives two vectors (u, and v).  What do these vectors represent?  The only reference I could find was the comment saying `"// U   u U-D Covariance Matrix (n, nn)"` I assume that one of these vectors is supposed to represent the new measurement (presumably v).  Is the other supposed to represent the co-variance of the measurement?  How are these values expected to be inserted?
2. Normally, the Kalman Filter will not be expecting measurements on regular time-intervals.  Rather, I would expect that a time would accompany every reading indicating the actual time that it occurs.  In the examples given, a constant value (called Period) is used.  Moreover, none of the virtual functions in the EKFilter class can recieve any inputs.  How can one use time as an input corresponding to a new measurement?  Similarly, the example given has constant R and Q matrices.  How can one use the co-variance as an input corresponding to a reading?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used the library so can't help. However, the following has caught my eye: *"Normally, the Kalman Filter will not be expecting measurements on regular time-intervals. Rather, I would expect that a time would accompany every reading indicating the actual time that it occurs."* Could you point me to some books/papers that deal with the Kalman filter on irregularly-timed observations? Thanks

Comment: @aix: irregular time steps can be easily introduced by changing the noises variances.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: I see what you're saying. Would still love some to see some textbook (or more advanced) treatment of the subject. Any pointers?

Comment: @aix: no. I was taught Kalman filter as a sort of do-it-yourself-it-takes-under-one-page-of-computations thing.

Comment: @aix check out the wikipedia page on Kalman Filters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application.2C_technical

Comment: @aix: notice that the calculations involve Delta(t), and not just a fixed t.  Each measurement's time value is the ammount of time that elapsed since the previous measurement.

Answer (score 0):

`u` is the control input.  It's usually something like linear and angular velocity.

`v` is now called `z`, it's the observation vector.

Data is usually interpolated so it's on a constant interval. Your measurement covariances, Q and R will be constant in the system as well.